# Find characters in PDF, return whole word

Tags: applescript

Apologies, my AppleScripting knowledge is very basic, however, I understand general scripting as I have PowerShell knowledge.

I would like a simple line of script that can search an open PDF for characters e.g. "Lon" and return the whole word e.g. "London" as a variable.

If you would like to have a laugh at my pathetic attempt see below:

```
tell application "Preview"
    set newfile to (get word 1 of text of "Lon*")
end tell
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preview** is not well scriptable using basic *vanilla* **AppleScript**, however, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* uses [**Skim**](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io) as the **PDF Reader**, and can do what you are asking:

```appleascipt
considering case
    tell application "Skim" to ¬
        set the targetWord to the first word of ¬
            the text of the front document where it starts with "Lon"
end considering
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>